# How to create a hyperlink that can only be followed by search engine

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is there a way to create a hyperlink in HTML that the search engine knows where to follow but the human cannot follow? something like following.

```
<a href='http://helloacm.com' onclick='javascript:void(0)'>helloacm.com</a>
```

When users click the hyperlink, it still redirects.. so my question is how to disable it?

Comment: have you tried `return false`?

Comment: make your link hidden in this way it is not readable or viewable by a human but it can be seen with search engine.

`<a href='http://helloacm.com' onclick='javascript:void(0)' style="display:none;">helloacm.com</a>`

Comment: return false does do the tricks, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search Engine always follow all the link. If you want to Create no follow link than use-

```
<a href="http://helloacm.com" rel="nofollow">Link Text</a>
```

And if you want to only search engine follow the link. No human can follow the Link. Then 
Use Display none CSS proparty.

```
<a style="display:none" href="http://helloacm.com">Link Text</a>
```

This link is hide for human but search engine follow this link. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the link as anik4e mentioned with display: none, or setting the color the same as the background color, or using something like text-indent:-9999px etc.

Be aware that displaying content to search engines only is against Google's guidelines though (in most cases), so if you are thinking of doing this for any nefarious reasons it may do more harm then good.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en